# uptodate list of excel supported functions in Apache POI

Tags: excel, function, apache-poi, formulas, array-formulas

I'm searching an up to date list of functions supported by Apache POI.
The newest I found is this one : http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval-devguide.html#appendixA, but it is from fev.2012 and I didn't found the version number, so it may from version 3.8b5 or 3.7 which was released in 29/10/2010 : it is not so fresh news ...
I'm currently using POI3.9 but I plan to migrate to 3.10 because in the version 3.10 presentation paragraph there : http://poi.apache.org/index.html, it is written "enhancements (especially in the number of Formula Functions supported)."
So, do you know if there is any more recent functions list anywhere ? (either for 3.9 final or for 3.10 b2 ?)
Another question (linked to the other one) : do you know if matrix formulas are supported in version 3.9 or 3.10 ?
Best regards,
Herve

Answer (score 3):

You can get the list from the Apache POI source tree, or with some Java code, but it does require a tiny bit of work either way.

If you want to do it in code, you need to use the [FunctionEval.getSupportedFunctionNames() method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/eval/FunctionEval.html#getSupportedFunctionNames%28%29), which will return a list of the functions which are implemented in your version of Apache POI. It won't, however, tell you which classes/methods implement those. To get a list of functions that POI knows the existence of, but has no implementation for, you need the related [FunctionEval.getNotSupportedFunctionNames() method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/eval/FunctionEval.html#getNotSupportedFunctionNames%28%29). Note that the latter won't be exhaustive, as if POI doesn't know the name of a function it won't be able to tell you what it isn't!

For the Analysis ToolPak function, there's a matching set of methods available. Those are [AnalysisToolPak.getSupportedFunctionNames()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/atp/AnalysisToolPak.html#getSupportedFunctionNames%28%29) and [AnalysisToolPak.getNotSupportedFunctionNames()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/atp/AnalysisToolPak.html#getNotSupportedFunctionNames%28%29)

Alternately, you can find what you want from the source tree.

Firstly, you need to look at [FunctionEval.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/eval/FunctionEval.java), which defines the lookup of the formula function IDs to classes which implement the logic. Wherever POI implements a given function, you'll find an entry in the main lookup block in that class. For example,

```
retval[66] = new TimeFunc();
retval[67] = CalendarFieldFunction.DAY;
```

In some cases, it's obvious to work out what function in excel a given function ID has. In others, you'll need to look them up. For that, you need [functionMetadata.txt](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/resources/main/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/function/functionMetadata.txt). Here, you'll see entries like:

```
66      TIME    3       3       V       V V V           
67      DAY     1       1       V       V
```

From that, we can see that function 66 is the `TIME` function in Excel, and we know it is implemented. Likewise, function 67 is `DAY` and that's also present.

If we look a bit further down FunctionEval we see this bit:

```
retval[74] = new Now();

retval[76] = new Rows();
```

Looking up in functionMetadata.txt, we can see that 74 `NOW` and 76 `ROWS` are both implemented, but 75 `AREAS` is currently *not* implemented.

In addition, there are a handful of other functions which come from the Analysis Toolpack. For those, you'll need to look in the source for [AnalysisToolPak](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/atp/AnalysisToolPak.java). In the `createFunctionsMap` section, you'll see in there lines like:

```
 r(m, "YEARFRAC", YearFrac.instance);
 r(m, "YIELD", null);
```

That tells you that the `YEARFRAC` function is implemented, but the `YIELD` one is not.